# Extract content from folder inside of zip archive

Tags: python, python-2.7, gitlab

I'm trying to get a zip file from a GitLab repo, access the only folder that is inside of it (folder name always starts with the same string), and copy the contents of the folder in another zip file.

Example gitlab_repo.zip:

```
gitlab_repo.zip
---------------------
 gitlab_repo_folder
  ├── subfolder
  |   ├── subfolder_file_1
  |   └── subfolder_file_2
  ├── file_1
  └── file_2
```

Example final.zip: (expected output)

```
final.zip
---------------------
  ┌── subfolder
  |   ├── subfolder_file_1
  |   └── subfolder_file_2
  ├── file_1
  └── file_2
```

The code snippet I have currently, which writes everything(including the folder) to a new archive:

```
final = '/tmp/final.zip'
gitlab_repo='https://gitlab.com/...'
r = requests.get(gitlab_repo, auth=('user', 'pass'))
open(final, 'wb').write(r.content)
```

**Aditional Info:**

This code will be triggered every time there is a push to the repository, so i need to automate the process

**My Python skill level:** I watched some youtube videos and I'm following a Python class on Udemy

Any help or hints for what library should I use to achieve this as efficiently as possible is much appriciated!

Comment: So, for clarification, you want a library to extract a zip file and look for contents in the only folder in the zip file, and then copy it to the a new zip file? A simple google search returns this library https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html . I might post a full solution for you when I get home.

Comment: thx for the reply! i added some additional info to clarify my situation, especially my skill level

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this ZIP is just an export of some git repository. Therefore the most efficient way to periodically ZIP file of some subdirectory in this repository is to just pull the changes to a local clone of the whole repository and zip this single directory.

Something like:

```
cd gitlab_repo
git pull
cd gitlab_repo_folder
zip -9r $TEMPDIR/output.zip .
```

Comment: thx for the reply! to clarify, this will be triggered by push events to the repo